# Rails set has_many value dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an entity: `book` of class Book.

The entity class has `has_many` relation with other tables, `pages` for example.

Let's say that `page_1` and `page_2` are valid values that I'de like to save. The non-dynamic version would be something like:

```
entity.pages = [page_1, page_2]
```

How can I set this dynamically?

I tried using `send` (which works fine for has_one) with no luck:

```
attr = :pages # my dynamic attribute 

book.send(attr) = [page_1, page_2]
# SyntaxError: unexpected '=', expecting end-of-input
# mc.send(:diagnoses, '=') = [s]
#                           ^
```

When I use `<<` it seems to work:

```
book.send(attr) << page_1
```

but the issue is that I need to support deletion, e.g. if the book had page3, and now it has page1 and page2.

I don't want to use `eval`, both due to performance and security. Not sure it's related, but these dynamic attributes all have the same class - has__many with a dynamic condition.

Comment: have you tried `book.public_send("#{attr}=", [page_1, page_2])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format is to call the setter (assignment) method.  Which is usually the attribute followed by an equal sign.  In your case, you want `pages=`

```
book.send(attr.to_s + '=', [page_1, page_2] )
```

Equivalent to

```
book.send('pages=', [page_1, page_2])
```

which is...

```
book.pages=([page_1, page_2])
```

or more conventionally written

```
book.pages = [page_1, page_2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `book.association(:pages).target`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.